# Can I change AssemblyInformationalVersion on an already compiled assembly?

Tags: c#, fileversioninfo, assemblyfileversion

We use svn revision for the [ProductBuildPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.productprivatepart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of our FileVersionInfo . Because we're above revision 65536, we had to mod the number. 
To compensate, we stick the real number in the [AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
This is easy enough when we build the assemblies from source.

However, we have an assembly generated by SGen for performance. Is there an easy way to change/add an AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute on an already built assembly?

Comment: Decompile it with ildasm.exe, edit, put back together with ilasm.exe.  Generating a new product version for every single SC commit is ... special.

Comment: @Thomas Jaskula: No, SGen - to speed up the Xml deserialization code.

Comment: @Hans: Not every single commit, but every "continuous" product build, yes. Otherwise, how do you tell them apart?